# I am trying to have the total payment from some data that coming from firebase (react native)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

there is a payment data with date of the pay I am trying to have the total payment for the past 6 months

```
export function GetTotelPayment() {
  const curent=moment().format('MMMM')
  return async (dispatch) => {
    let totel=0;
    await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("payments")
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .collection("payment")
      .orderBy("creation", "desc")
      .get()
      .then((result) => {
       result.docs.map((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          const Time = moment.unix(data.creation).format("MMMM");
          if(curent==Time){
            totel=totel+Number(data.payed)+Number(data.dubt);
          }
        });
      });
      dispatch({ type: GET_TOTELPAYMENT, TotelPayment:totel });
  };
}
```

I get the first month how to make it get the last 6 month

Comment: can you share the payment collection schema ?

Comment: do you mean how it stored in the data base ? I save it like this creation March 5, 2021 at 9:35:44 PM UTC+2
dubt "500"
patientId "froHM6mYnoJ6HCQyvMUJ"
patientName "qwe"
payed "200"

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "get the first month"? Is `result.docs` only the first month?

Comment: I wont to get this month total payment and I want to get it for at lest the past six month I am trying to build a chart for payment and I need the total payment for this past 6 month

Comment: Seems you just need to filter the query result to include only those tuples covering the last six months, then reduce the filtered result into the total payment sum. Can you include what `result.docs` is?

Comment: thanks for you help I already figure it out