# I am trying to pass multiple props in picker react native but have some problem

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
 <Picker
    selectedValue={patient}
    style={{ color: 'white' }}
    onValueChange={(itemValue) => {
    if (itemValue != "0") {
        setPatientId(itemValue.slice(0, 20))
        setPatient(itemValue.slice(20))
    }
    }}
     >
  <Picker.Item label="Chosse A Patient" value="0" />
      {data.map((item) => {
          return <Picker.Item label={item.name} value={item.id + item.name} key={item.id} />;
       })}
</Picker>
```

here I am send all the data then I use itemValue.slice(20) the problem with this approach is that after choosing the item it reverse to the default value

Comment: What is the default value? This appears to be a controlled input so there is no default value. Does `setPatient(itemValue.slice(20))` match any option picker values? Can you include a more [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example? Can you try reproducing this issue in a running [Expo Snack](https://expo.io/) that we can live debug in and include a link to it in your question?

Comment: thank for commenting I found a solution by adding setPatient(itemValue ) and adding  setPatientName(itemValue.slice(20)) I don't understand why it needed to be done this way at lest it works now

Comment: I have another problem if you can have a look at it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66498738/i-am-trying-to-have-the-total-payment-from-some-data-that-coming-from-firebase

Answer (score 0):

```
<Picker
    selectedValue={patient}
    style={{ color: 'white' }}
    onValueChange={(itemValue) => {
    if (itemValue != "0") {
        setPatient(itemValue)
        setPatientId(itemValue.slice(0, 20))
        setPatientName(itemValue.slice(20))
    }
    }}
     >
  <Picker.Item label="Chosse A Patient" value="0" />
      {data.map((item) => {
          return <Picker.Item label={item.name} value={item.id + item.name} key={item.id} />;
       })}
</Picker>
```

Comment: my problem is related to this. I look for many solutions but didn't find any of the correct one . can you please solve my question its important for me . any help would be appreciated
[my question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74446229/how-to-show-selected-item-for-each-picker-component-with-api-in-react-native)